# Android Volley JSON Post Login

Tags: java, android, post, android-volley

I am trying to create a login that takes a username and pin and post that information along with the authenticated header to the server and retrieves a JSON object. The `getHeaders()` is returning the correct data and the public `byte[] getBody()` is also returning the correct information. However, I am still getting a 415 error. Is there anything in this code I am not seeing?

```
import android.util.Base64;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "https://foobar.com";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public LoginRequest(String username, String password,    Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("userpin", password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

        // Temporary Auth
        String username = "abc@foobar.com";
        String password = "password";
        String credentials = username + ":" + password;
        String base64EncodedCredentials =
                Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);

        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        //RAW PAYLOAD
        // {"username":"abc@foobar.com","userpin":"1234"}
        String str = "{\"username\":\"" + params.get("username") + "\",\"userpin\":\"" + params.get("userpin") + "\"}";

        return str.getBytes();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json";
    }

}
```

Comment: to help clarify, the username and password for the authentication in getHeaders(), is different from the login username and password that will be entered by the user under username and userpin.

Comment: Try by changing `application/json` into `application/json;charset=utf-8` . if it not work the remove this line `headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");`

Comment: Thank you so much. Removing headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json"); solved the problem. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to mark this as answered or how to vote up.

Comment: It's comment not an answer . No need for Upvote . :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try by changing:

```
application/json
```

into:

```
application/json;charset=utf-8
```

If it does not work then remove this line:

```
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

try update your function 'getBody()' to

```
    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        try
        {
            JSONObject aux = new JSONObject(params);
            return aux.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```